# Unable to print a sentence in python 3.7

Tags: python

I have created a function named *user_choice()* using Jupyter Notebook.[image] This function is expecting an valid integer input from the user and prints the same. If a user any input other than integer then it should display an error message like " Sorry that is not a digit!" and it  will again ask the user to enter valid input.

Below is my code for the function user_choice()

```
def user_choice():
    choice = "WRONG"
    
    while choice.isdigit() == False:
        choice = input("Enter a digit(0-10): ")
        if choice.isdigit == False:
            print("Sorry that is not a digit!")
        
    return(int(choice))
```

On calling the above function and entering non integer value, It is not displaying the message "Sorry that is not a digit!"

```
Enter a digit(0-10): ten
Enter a digit(0-10):
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` in your `while` loop; just put the `print` before the `choice = input` line

Comment: check if my answer solves your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just forget brackets after `.isdigit` method in `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use recursive call

```
def user_choice(choice="WRONG"):    
    if choice.isdigit() == False:
        choice = raw_input("Enter a digit(0-10): ") #use input for higher python version, mine is 2.7 hence used raw_input
        if choice.isdigit() == False:
            print("Sorry that is not a digit!")
            user_choice(choice)
        else:
            print("Captured:"+choice)
            return(int(choice))
```

A shorter version:

```
def user_choice(choice="WRONG"):    
    if choice.isdigit() == False:
        choice = raw_input("Input must be a digit(0-10): ") #use input for higher python version, mine is 2.7 hence used raw_input
        user_choice(choice)
    else:
        print("Captured:"+choice)
        return(int(choice))
```